# Which LFT is right?

Tags: linear-fractional-transformation

The question is,
Find an LFT that maps |z|<=1 onto |w|<=1 so that z=i/2 is mapped onto w=0. Sketch the images of the lines x=const and y=const.

By searching and solving, I found several different solutions.

1. $w=\frac{2}{3}(z-\frac{1}{2})$
2. $w=\frac{i-2z}{iz+2}$
3. $w=\frac{z-i/2}{1-iz/2}$

Which one is the right thing?

Comment: Option 1 is not a solution because it operates a shrinking by factor $2/3$ : therefore, the unit disk cannot be mapped **onto** itself...

Comment: The two others are good. For the last one, multiply its numerator and denominator by 2 in order to make it look like the other one...

Comment: @Jean Marie I think the answer is second one. But the last one is slightly different with second one. That makes me little confused.

Comment: Indeed your sol. (3) doesn't map the unit disk on itself. For example, the image of $\frac{1-i}{2}$ is $1-i$ !